# Docker toolbox volumes on windows doesn't refresh changes on container

Tags: docker, boot2docker, dockerfile, dockerhub

I am starting with docker on windows and I am trying to use volumes for manage data in containers.

My host environment is a:

- Windows 8.1
- Docker Toolbox 1.8.
- Virtual Box 5.0.6

I've created a ngnix image using the following Dockerfile.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM centos:6.6

MAINTAINER afym

ENV WEBPORT 80

RUN yum -y update; yum clean all
RUN yum -y install epel-release; yum clean all
RUN yum -y install nginx; yum clean all
RUN echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

VOLUME /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE $WEBPORT

CMD [ "/usr/sbin/nginx" ]
```

I've created a ngnix container using the following command.

```
docker run -d --name nge -v //c/Users/src:/usr/share/nginx/html -p 8082:80 ng1

b738fef9cc4d135416a8cca4caf869acf944319b7c3c61129b11f37f9d891598
```

Then I go to my browser and I can see the web page:

[image]

However when I make a change on my index.html file it doesn't refresh on browser

**Editing my file**

[image]

**On my browser (ctrl + f5)**

[image]

I went to the VirtualBox machine to check if my shared directories options is ok.

[image]

Then I inspect my nge container with the following command.

```
docker inspect ng1
```

**Docker inspect**

[image]

***What is happening with volumes? Why I can not see my changes?***

Comment: I am using the docker cp command for now I am managing my files as: docker cp /C/Users/src/index.html nge:/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html (of course you can cp a complete directory). If someone found the solution it would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a couple of days I could find the solution.

Firstable docker on windows even on MAC uses a **boot2docker** instance on VirtualBox.

### Diagrams

**On MAC**

[image]

**On Windows**

[image]

Next, the official docker's documentation says :

[docker volume](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-file-as-a-data-volume)

```
Docker Machine tries to auto-share your /Users (OS X) or C:\Users (Windows) directory
```

However, after find a solution I decided to change the default c/Users to another path just for keep order. With this in mind I did the following steps:

- Define your own workspace directory. In my case is **/e/arquitectura** (optional. If you want you can use the default path which is **/c/Users**)
- Verify the configuration on the Virtual Machine (In default machine go to **> Configuration > Share directories**)

[image]

- Join to the default machine and mount the directory using the alias name

```
  sudo mount -t vboxsf alias-name-virtualbox  some-path-in-boot2docker

  # In my case (boot2docker instance)
  $ cd
  $ mkdir arquitectura
  $ sudo mount -t vboxsf arquitectura /arquitectura
```

- Finally create a new container or restart an existing one if you haven't changed the c/user/ path

```
# In my case (docker client)
$ docker run -d --name nge -v //arquitectura/src:/usr/share/nginx/html -p 8081:80 ng1
```

Now it works.

[image]