# Local changes not reflected in docker container

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, containers, docker-volume

I have a simple react application (default created using create-react-app). I am trying to run the container with -v tag so that changes to the local files get reflected in docker. But for some reason the changes are not being reflected in the app. Only when I rebuild the image, the app gets updated.

Version Info: 
OS: Windows Home x64 
Docker Toolbox 
Oracle Virtual Box v 6.1 
React project file structure:

```
simple-react-app
│   README.md
│   Dockerfile.dev    
│   package.json
└───public
│   │   ...
└───src
    │   App.css
    │   App.js
    │   ...
```

Here are the contents of the Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

`Build Command: docker build -t my:simple-react-app -f Dockerfile.dev .`

`Run Command: docker run -it -p 3000:3000 -v /app/node_modules -v pwd:/app my:simple-react-app`

Here pwd is a sub-directory of C:\Users

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker toolbox volumes on windows doesn't refresh changes on container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33352104/docker-toolbox-volumes-on-windows-doesnt-refresh-changes-on-container)

Answer (score 0):

could you please try replace the pwd with exact path of the directory.  I suspect pwd is being taken as literal and not being translated to correct path.

i.e.  docker run -v d:/data:/data alpine ls /data

Comment: @NotABot  Can u provide information please? like what u typed and current directory names etc., where you running the command.